# How to programmatically create an order in Magento 2 w/o using a cart/quote?

Tags: magento2, admin-order-create

I've read a lot of answers to similar question, however all of them are suggesting to create cart/quote and then call `placeOrder()` or something similar.

I need to create 'historical' orders. They differ from 'normal' orders:

1. They shouldn't affect current stocks
2. They may have items that are currently out of stock or disabled
3. They may have items prices that are different from current prices
4. Taxes, shipping prices, totals/subtotals are calculated in the past, so we should apply 'historical' values, and shouldn't let Magento 2 calculate them

Any help/thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up creating order directly, skipping quote/cart.

```
/* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory */
$order = $orderFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId);
$order
        ->setGlobalCurrencyCode($currency)
        ->setBaseCurrencyCode($currency)
        ->setStoreCurrencyCode($currency)
        ->setOrderCurrencyCode($currency);

/* @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderPaymentRepositoryInterface $orderPaymentRepository */
$orderPayment = $orderPaymentRepository->create();
$method = 'checkmo';
$orderPayment->setMethod($method);
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);

/* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer */
$order
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->setCustomerEmail($customer->getEmail())
        ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
        ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
        ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
        ->setCustomerIsGuest(0);

/* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\AddressRepository $orderAddressRepository */
$orderAddress = $orderAddressRepository->create();
$orderAddress
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setAddressType($addressType) // \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address::TYPE_BILLING and then \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address::TYPE_SHIPPING
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->setPrefix($prefix)
        ->setFirstname($firstName)
        ->setMiddlename($middleName)
        ->setLastname($lastName)
        ->setCompany($company)
        ->setStreet($address)
        ->setCity($city)
        ->setPostcode($postCode)
        ->setTelephone($phone)
        ->setFax($fax)
        ->setCountryId($countryCode)
        ->setRegionId($regionId);
$order->setBillingAddress($orderAddress);
// repeat for shipping address $order->setShippingAddress($orderAddress);

$order
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setShippingDescription('Flat Rate - Fixed');
$order->setCreatedAt(strtotime($orderDateTimeString));

// add order item
/* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
/* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $orderItemFactory */
$orderItem = $orderItemFactory->create();
$orderItem
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setQuoteItemId(0)
        ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
        ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
        ->setName($product->getName())
        ->setSku($product->getSku())
        ->setTotalQtyOrdered($qty)
        ->setQtyOrdered($qty)
        ->setPrice($itemPrice)
        ->setBasePrice($itemPrice)
        ->setOriginalPrice($itemPrice)
        ->setBaseOriginalPrice($itemPrice)
        ->setTaxAmount($rowTax)
        ->setBaseTaxAmount($rowTax)
        ->setTaxPercent($rowTaxPercent)
        ->setDiscountAmount($rowDiscount)
        ->setBaseDiscountAmount($rowDiscount)
        ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
        ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)
        ->setWeight(1)
        ->setIsVirtual(0);
$order->addItem($orderItem);
// repeat for each order item

// set status
$order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING); // depends on your needs
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);

// set totals
$order->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal);
$order->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
$order->setBaseSubtotal($baseSubtotal);
$order->setSubtotal($subtotal);
$order->setBaseTaxAmount($baseTaxAmount);
$order->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
$order->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseDiscountAmount);
$order->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
$order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($baseSubtotalInclTax);
$order->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotalInclTax);
$order->setTotalItemCount($totalItemCount);
$order->setTotalQtyOrdered($totalQtyOrdered);

// set shipping amounts
$order->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
$order->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
$order->setShippingTaxAmount($shippingTax);
$order->setBaseShippingTaxAmount($shippingTax);
$order->setShippingInclTax($shippingAmount + $shippingTax);
$order->setBaseShippingInclTax($shippingAmount + $shippingTax);

// set total paid if needed
$order->setTotalPaid($paid);
$order->setBaseTotalPaid($paid);
$order->save();
```

Comment: If we open order from admin it's giving fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function `getId()` on null in `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info.php:227`

Answer (score 1):

@Rustem, you can try this code which is used to create historical orders.

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$_storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$_formkey = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');
$quote = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
$quoteManagement = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement');
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$customerRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$orderService = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService');
$_productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$_orderRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService');
$_invoiceService = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
$_transaction = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction');
$_order = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
$_convertOrder = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order');
$_resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$cartRepositoryInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');
$cartManagementInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface');


$store = $_storeManager->getStore();
$websiteId = $_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customer = $customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);


$payments = array();

        if ($datum['grand_total'] > 0) {
            $tempOrder = array();
            $tempOrder['currency_id'] = 'USD';
            $tempOrder['email'] = $datum['customer_email'];
            $tempOrder['shipping_address'] = $datum['shipping_address'];
            if (isset($datum['billing_address']))
                $tempOrder['billing_address'] = $datum['billing_address'];


                $tempOrder['grand_total'] = $datum['grand_total'];
                $tempOrder['shipping_amount'] = $datum['shipping_amount'];
                $tempOrder['tax_amount'] = $datum['tax_amount'];
                $tempOrder['shipping_description'] = "Free Shipping";//$datum['shipping_description'];
                $tempOrder['state'] = $datum['state'];
                $tempOrder['status'] = $datum['status'];


                $tempOrder['payments'] = $datum['payments'];

                foreach ($datum['trackings'] as $tracking) {
                    $tempOrder['shipping_description'] = $tracking['carrier_name'];
                }

                $tempOrder['items'] = $datum['items'];
                if ($datum['created_at']) {
                    $tempOrder['created_at'] = $datum['created_at'];
                }

                $orderData = $tempOrder;


                $store = $_storeManager->getStore();
                $websiteId = $_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
                $customer = $customerFactory->create();
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address

                $quote1 = $quote->create(); //Create object of quote
                if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
                    //If not avilable then create this customer

                    $quote1->setCheckoutMethod('guest')
                        ->setCustomerId(null)
                        ->setCustomerEmail($orderData['email'])
                        ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
                        ->setCustomerGroupId(0);
                    //$logger->info("Customer not exist " . $orderData['email'] . "\r\n");
                    //continue;
                } else {
                    $customer = $customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
                    $quote1->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
                }

                // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly


                $quote1->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote


                $quote1->setCurrency();


                 //add items in quote
                $shipping_method = "";
                foreach ($orderData['items'] as $item) {
                    $product = $productFactory->create();
                    $product->load($product->getIdBySku($item['sku']));


                    if ($product->getId()) {
                        $product->setPrice($item['price']);

                        $product->setTaxClassId(0);
                        $quote1->addProduct($product, $item['qty_ordered']);


                    }
                }


                //Set Address to quote
                if (isset($orderData['billing_address'])) {
                    $quote1->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['billing_address']);
                } else {
                    $billing = $orderData['shipping_address'];
                    $billing['address_type'] = 'billing';
                    $quote1->getBillingAddress()->addData($billing);
                }
                $orderData['shipping_address']['p21_freight'] = "FREIGHT FREE";


                $quote1->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

                // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

                $shippingAddress = $quote1->getShippingAddress();
                $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                    ->collectShippingRates()
                    ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
                // $quote->setPaymentMethod('elementpayment'); //payment method
                $quote1->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory


                $quote1->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

                $payment_method = "";
                $payment = array("method" => "checkmo");


                    $payment_method = $payment['method'];


                // Set Sales Order Payment
                $quote1->getPayment()->importData($payment);


                // Collect Totals & Save Quote
                $quote1->collectTotals()->save();



                $manual_date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                if (isset($orderData['created_at'])) {
                    //  4/26/2016
                    $date = explode("/", $orderData['created_at']);
                    //print_r($date);
                    $orderCustomData['created_at'] = $date[2] . "-" . str_pad($date[0], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-" . str_pad($date[1], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . " 05:05:05";
                    $manual_date = $orderCustomData['created_at'];
                    //exit;

                }


                $orderCustomData['shipping_amount'] = $orderData['shipping_amount'];
                $orderCustomData['base_shipping_amount'] = $orderData['shipping_amount'];
                $orderCustomData['grand_total'] = $orderData['grand_total'];
                $orderCustomData['base_grand_total'] = $orderData['grand_total'];
                $orderCustomData['tax_amount'] = $orderData['tax_amount'];
                $orderCustomData['base_tax_amount'] = $orderData['tax_amount'];
                $orderCustomData['shipping_description'] = $orderData['shipping_description'];
                $orderCustomData['state'] = 'complete';
                $orderCustomData['status'] = 'complete';

                // Create Order From Quote
                $order = "";
                try {

                    $order = $quoteManagement->submit($quote1, $orderCustomData);


                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }
```

Comment: Thanks @iyappan-perumal. Why do you call `$quote1->setInventoryProcessed(false)` with `false` value? Doesn't it mean that inventory will be processed because it is not processed yet?

Comment: I also noticed that Magento executes reindexings (stocks, prices). However this just adds an overhead, because no changes in stocks or prices could happen when historical order is created.

Comment: @RustemZinnatullin did you tried creating order by commenting the  `$quote1->setInventoryProcessed(false)` the order created without any issue.

Comment: Hi @iyappan-perumal, yes I tried - the same behavior. I also tried changing `false` to `true`, but got a error on reindexing. In any case I wasn't able to make the solution not to decrease stocks.

Comment: @RustemZinnatullin

Just before 

`$quote1->setInventoryProcessed(true)`
Add below code 

`$itemsForReindex = $this->stockManagement->registerProductsSale($items, $quote->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$this->itemsForReindex->setItems($itemsForReindex);`

You will get more info about this from this file https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Observer/SubtractQuoteInventoryObserver.php

Comment: Hi @ParthThummar, I think this solution won't eliminate the stocks decreasing, will it?

Comment: failed to open stream:  bootstrap.php not found

Answer (score 0):

@Rustem in you explanation if there is any kind of tax rule is there how to overcome that?
i am pushing product price 75 but it get changed to 93  when order is created

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/200114)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
class OrderCreator
{
private $objectManager;

public function __construct()
{
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $this->objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
}

public function createOrderFromQuote($existingQuoteId, $customerId)
{
    $existingQuote = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository::class)->get($existingQuoteId);

    $newQuote = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory::class)->create();
    $newQuote->setStoreId(1);
    $newQuote->assignCustomer($this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class)->getById($customerId));
    $newQuote->setIsActive(true);

    foreach ($existingQuote->getItems() as $item) {
        $product = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::class)->get($item->getSku());
        $quoteItem = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::class);
        $quoteItem->setProduct($product);
        $quoteItem->setQuote($newQuote);
        $quoteItem->setQty($item->getQty());
        $newQuote->addItem($quoteItem);
    }

    $shippingAddress = $newQuote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');

    $newQuote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
    $newQuote->collectTotals();
    $newQuote->getPayment()->setMethod("checkmo");
    $newQuote->save();

    $cartManagement = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface::class);
    $orderInterface = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class);
    
    try {
        $orderId = $cartManagement->placeOrder($newQuote->getId());
        $order = $orderInterface->load($orderId);
        $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
        echo "Increment ID: " . $incrementId . "\n";
        echo "Order ID: " . $orderId . "\n";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error placing order: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}